# Multiple types in Elasticsearch Query for specific types only

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I created index called "testindex" and three types called type1, type2, type3. I need filter data from these three types. I filtered like this.

```
GET testindex/type1,type2,type3/_search
{"query":{
    "filtered":{
        "query":{
            "match_phrase_prefix":{"title":"c"}
        },
        "filter":{
            "bool":{
                "must":[
                    {
                        "term":{
                          "status": "1"
                        }    
                    }
                    ]
            }

        }

    }

}
```

This works fine but the issue is **type3** doesn't have **status** field. I need consider filter only for type1 and type2 not for type3. I need a help to solve this.

Comment: What do you mean by " type3 doesn't have status field. I need consider filter only for type1 and type2 not for type3"? If the `status` field doesn't exist for type3 what do you expect to happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do this is to use an `or` filter which would basically select:

- either documents of type `test1` or `test2` having `status = 1`
- or documents of type `test3` with no condition on the `status` field

This query should work:

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "match_phrase_prefix": {
          "title": "h"
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "or": [
          {
            "bool": {
              "must": [
                {
                  "term": {
                    "status": "1"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "terms": {
                    "_type": [
                      "test1",
                      "test2"
                    ]
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "term": {
              "_type": "test3"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```